# How to install Windows 7 on a hybrid hard disk

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, hybrid-storage

I purchased a new notebook and I'm trying to reinstall Windows. However, I missed that the hard disk used is a hybrid one – a [Seagate Momentus ST1000lM024](http://www.seagate.com/files/staticfiles/support/docs/samsung-ds/100698122c.pdf). The disk is shown as:

- Disk 0 with 8 GB (SSD)
- Disk 1 with 1 TB

I deleted all partitions – now I'm unable to reinstall Windows.  I tried to reinstall Windows 7 (using a USB drive) however the installation creates two partitions.

- A small partition used for the system, created on the disk 0
- The primary partition

When I start windows for the first time, the machine is restarted.

update:

Short story, i was able to reinstall windows using only the recovery disk. So, in this notebook, **it is not possible to install any os but the supplied with the manufacturer** (like the old good days of IBM machines).   And the notebook was a Samsung, "was", because it showed randomly a vertical line on the screen, followed with some other random problems...so i returned it.

Answer (score 1):

1. That is not a hybrid drive
2. The 8gb SSD is separate from the spinning hard drive and is used for hibernation ([Rapid Start](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/responsiveness-technologies.html)) by a special Intel driver.
3. What make and model of laptop?
4. You may need a Sata or other Intel driver loaded during setup (install) of windows 7
5. You are best to use the factory restore discs to install Windows 7.